# phpMyAdmin using dockerised database

Tags: docker, databases, networking

I have installed mariadb inside docker container, and mariadb is running properly inside that container. I want to get access of mariadb through phpMyAdmin from outside docker container.

What will I have to do for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. [Expose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) the server port in the Dockerfile
2. get the IP that the container is listening on (*e.g.* `docker inspect code-rade_cache_1 |jq .[0].NetworkSettings.Networks[].IPAddress` ) -- note that you will need [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed  on your computer to do this
3. Set the connection in the [mysqlphpadmin](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_host)